# Is this a good use case for ndb async urlfetch tasklets?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, urlfetch

I want to move to `ndb`, and have been wondering whether to use async `urlfetch` [tasklets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#urlfetch). I'm not sure I fully understand how it works, as the documentation is somewhat poor, but it seems quite promising for this particular use case.

Currently I use async `urlfetch` like this. It is far from actual threading or parallel code, but it has still improved performance quite significantly, compared to just sequential requests.

```
def http_get(url):
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=3)
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc,url)
    return rpc

rpcs = []
urls = [...] # hundreds of urls

while rpcs < 10:
    rpcs.append(http_get(urls.pop()))

while rpcs:
    rpc = rpcs.pop(0)
    result = rpc.get_result()
    if result.status_code == 200:
        # append another item to rpcs
        # process result
    else:
        # re-append same item to rpcs
```

Please note that this code is simplified. The actual code catches exceptions, has some additional checks, and only tries to re-append the same item a few times. It makes no difference for this case.

I should add that processing the result does not involve any `db` operations.

Comment: If you're asking if using ndb for your use case is performant, wouldn't the solution be to measure the performance? It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually yes, it's a good idea to use async urlfetch here. How it's working (rough explanation):
- your code reach the point of async call. It triggers long background task and doesn't wait for it's result, but continue to execute. 
- task works in background, and when result is ready — it stores result somwhere, until you ask for it.

Simple example:

```
def get_fetch_all():
    urls = ["http://www.example.com/", "http://mirror.example.com/"]
    ctx = ndb.get_context()
    futures = [ctx.urlfetch(url) for url in urls]
    results = ndb.Future.wait_all(futures)
    # do something with results here
```

If you want to store result in ndb and make it more optimal — it's good idea to write custom tasklet for this.

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_data_and_store(url):
    ctx = ndb.get_context()
    # until we don't receive result here, this function is "paused", allowing other 
    # parallel tasks to work. when data will be fetched, control will be returned
    result = yield ctx.urlfetch("http://www.google.com/") 
    if result.status_code == 200:
        store = Storage(data=result.content)
        # async job to put data
        yield store.put_async()
        raise ndb.Return(True)
    else:
        raise ndb.Return(False)
```

And you can use this tasklet combined with loop in first sample. You should get list of ther/false values, indicating success of fetch.

I'm not sure, how much this will boost overall productivity (it depends on google side), but it should.

Comment: I have a question. When I have 100 URLs and use urlfetch as with the list comprehension in your example, won't the server initiate 100 connections at once? Can I limit this to not have more than 10 connections at once, like in the code I posted, to not strain the other server with too many simultaneous requests? I could probably just split `urls` into lists of 10, but then I cannot _re-fill_ the list to 10 items when a result has been processed. It seems like I could just use a combination of my code and custom tasklets - but there is probably not any benefit to it then.

Comment: As far, as I understood — if you trigger 100 connections — you won't have control oveer them. They are controlled by async. broker. So, if you need to limit bulks to 10, you need to take first 10 URL, submit them to processing, wait for their result, take next 10, and so on...

Comment: Actually, your code is doing actuall calls in async matter, so main reason of using ndb here — make saving data also async, but HTTP calls are much longer then storing data (I think google's cloud storages are fast enough), so I don't think you'll benifit much. I'd better try to tune batch size to see, how it helps.

Comment: Hmm you are right. I was hoping for this to be a more elegant way to use async urlfetch, but it seems pointless to use tasklets if no `ndb` operation is involved.

Comment: You're actually already using async urlfetch, so no need to add anything more.